# How to dynamically add the values in kendo Grid in editing state

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

In grid, I need to dynamically add a value to a column with a new row using a pop-up box. when I get dataSource I tried this method,

```
var firstItem = $('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[0];
firstItem.set('FirstName','The updated Name');
```

but it was useless. What should I do to achieve it? Thank you very much.
I look forward to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please refresh your grid after changed value in data source.

Example : `$('#Results').data('kendoGrid').refresh()`